# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle not setting authenticated user to session?

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I have a very basic Symfony2.1 setup with FOSUserBundle installed.

When registering all is well and I am redirected to my target path and the debug bar shows that I am authenticated as myself.

When logging in however, submitting the form with bad creds will reflect as such, but if I login with the correct creds, I get redirected to my target path but I'm still anon, so authentication is successful but not persisted in the session.

Am I missing something? I have followed the basic configuration pretty much exactly with little customisation. Unsure how to go about debugging this (experience with Symfony1, new to Symfony2).

FOSUserBundle's InteractiveLoginListener onSecurityInteractiveLogin has and correctly updates the user with last login date, I'm not sure at what point this would be bound to security.context if at all nor where to look.

Am I meant to register my own listener or is something not working? Searching the entire bundle for security.context seems to lead to this only being set for registration and resetting?

---

### security.yml

```
security:
    acl:
        connection: default

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        # SONATA:
        #     - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented

    firewalls:
        # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
        admin:
            switch_user:        true
            context:            user
            pattern:            /admin(.*)
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check

                # login success redirecting options (read further below)
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path:            /admin/dashboard
                target_path_parameter:          _target_path
                use_referer:                    false

                failure_path:   null
                use_referer:    true
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
                target:         /admin/login
            anonymous:    true
        # -> end custom configuration

        # default login area for standard users
        main:
            switch_user:        true
            context:            user
            pattern:            .*
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle

                # the user is redirected here when he/she needs to login
                login_path:                     /login

                # if true, forward the user to the login form instead of redirecting
                use_forward:                    false

                # submit the login form here
                check_path:                     /login_check

                # login success redirecting options (read further below)
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path:            /
                target_path_parameter:          _target_path
                use_referer:                    false

                # login failure redirecting options (read further below)
                failure_path:                   null
                failure_forward:                false

                # csrf token options
                csrf_parameter:                 _csrf_token
                intention:                      authenticate

            logout:             true
            anonymous:          true
        # -> end default configuration


    access_control:
        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # -> custom access control for the admin area of the URL
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login-check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        # -> end

        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Secured part of the site
        # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
        # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
        - { path: ^/admin, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true
```

---

### Logs

```
[2012-07-05 15:12:50] security.INFO: User "steve" has been authenticated successfully [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "security.interactive_login" to listener "FOS\UserBundle\Security\InteractiveLoginListener::onSecurityInteractiveLogin". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:50] doctrine.DEBUG: UPDATE fos_user_user SET last_login = ?, updated_at = ? WHERE id = ? ([{"date":"2012-07-05 16:12:50","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"},{"date":"2012-07-05 16:12:50","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"},1]) [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:50] event.DEBUG: Listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.request". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:50] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] request.INFO: Matched route "sonata_admin_dashboard" (parameters: "_controller": "Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CoreController::dashboardAction", "_route": "sonata_admin_dashboard") [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] security.DEBUG: Access is denied (user is not fully authenticated) by "/var/www/motoratings/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php" at line 70; redirecting to authentication entry point [] []
[2012-07-05 15:12:51] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point [] []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the answer was simply to clear my browser's cookies, for some reason I had 2 PHPSESSID cookies set.. no idea how that's even possible?

My assumption is that this was due to fiddling with this, and maybe because I had 2 firewalls which I later stripped down to 1?

It seemed that Symfony was cycling the PHPSESSID cookies, every page hit it was changing, so any authentication was on a session that wasn't persisted to the next- and thus gave me the described problem.

Is there a legitimate reason there'd be 2 cookies set?.. Surely it's not even possible to have 2 cookies of the same name set? I didn't investigate it properly before clearing them, I guess that must have had different paths or something?.. But yet they both seemed to be present on every request.

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark, but does your user class `getRoles()` method returns a ROLE_USER in any case because if this method does not return anything, the user will be considered as anonymous and thus not authenticated.

Comment: A stab is better than nothing! Sadly yes, array('ROLE_USER') is what is being returned, I'm using SonataUserBundle's User entity.

Answer (score 0):

Another stab in the dark, it seems that you are redirecting to `sonata_admin_dashboard` route, which resolves to `/admin/dashboard` url. According to your `security.yml` it seems that the user needs to have `ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN` role to access the page.

Comment: Another good guess, but I've tried it with both of those roles assigned. Additionally, the problem occurs on the frontend as well as back. My guess would be that should this be working however that the user would get an access denied error rather than nothing if this was the problem?

Comment: What is your login page? `/login` or `/admin/login` ?

Comment: I have both, one is the Sonata admin login, the other is the basic one that I believe ships with FOSUser? Both behave the same.

Comment: Actually no. They are different for each firewall. For each firewall context security token is saved in different session key. To access admin page you have to login through `admin` firewall's `login_path` e.g `admin/login`. See [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ContextListener.php#L70)

Comment: Okay, good to know, but still, neither login is persisting to the session, it always says anon.

Comment: Debug around the [ContextListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ContextListener.php) class. `handle()` method loads token from session and `onKernelRequest` saves the token. `contextKey` property of the class hold the current firewall name. Check that it is loading correct security token based on firewall.

Comment: Thanks for that @m2mdas, that at least gave me some basic knowledge to know where to start debugging this.